# Autolayout for Height working in iOS8 but not working in iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, autolayout

I have my UIImageView in the view which will download image from server and after downloading finish then my UIImageView height will be adjusted according to height of image but the problem is it is working perfectly in iOS8 but not in iOS7. In iOS7, the height is scaled to much more than I tried to set.  I am setting autolayout via IB

Here is the excerpt from my code  (default is 250)

```
 if(image.size.height<250) headerView.itemImageView.contentMode =      UIViewContentModeCenter;
                 else{


                   adjustedHeight =      image.size.height*320.0f/image.size.width;


                     imageHeight = adjustedHeight;

                     [headerView.heightContraintLayout setConstant:adjustedHeight];
                [headerView.itemImageView layoutIfNeeded];
 //after this line of code, I check the size of itemImageView is extended more than the adjestedHeight that I set in the previous line ( this only happened in iOS7 not iOS8
```

Answer (score 0):

You set the image view's content mode to "centre".

Try setting it to "Aspect Fill" or "Scale to Fill" according to what you need to achieve.

Comment: No, that's not the case because I always set contentMode to AspectFit in IB ( The IF case is never execute in normal case ).  Anyway, I already solved this problem by put more NSLayoutConstrainst between the bottom of UIImageView and superView. This way locked the size and does not make vertical blank space