# UIImageView with contentMode AspectFit break Autolayout height in iOS7 but working properly in iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, autolayout, uiviewcontentmode

According to my previous question. 
[Autolayout for Height working in iOS8 but not working in iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31889762/autolayout-for-height-working-in-ios8-but-not-working-in-ios7)

I use UIImageView which will display the image from server once the download finished.  I have autolayout constraint to define the height of UIImageView which I set via IB and has an outlet.

In my code, when I finished download the image I change the height of autolayout to match the height of my image. It works perfectly in iOS8 but in iOS7 which I tested via simulator always display the UIImageView height bigger than image size make the vertical area of top and bottom blank 
Please see the screenshot here

[image]

I totally don't understand. I didn't get any warning but the autolayout just didn't work to keep the UIImageView height in place to what I set it via [layoutConstraint setConstant:]

Please help

Answer (score 0):

In your other question you set the image view's content mode to "centre".

Try setting it to "Aspect Fill" or "Scale to Fill" according to what you need to achieve.